# Spark Inner Join and get Min()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am not able to join properly and get resultant columns and need to get min() of column after joining

```
 SELECT 
t.ad,
t.DId,
t.BY,
t.BM,
t.cid,
MIN(p.PS) AS PS 
FROM 
    Tempity t inner join  ples p 
    on t.cid = p.cid
    and p.PType = t.TeO 
    AND p.pto = 'cccc' 
    AND p.cid = 2
  GROUP BY t.aid
    ,t.DId
    ,t.BYear
    ,t.BM
    ,t.cid;
I am converting above sql query as
        val RS = Tempity.join(DF_LES,Tempity("cid") <=> DF_PLES("cid")&&   DF_PLES("clientid") <=> 2 && Tempity("TO") <=> DF_LES("PType") && DF_LES("pto") <=> "cccc" ,"inner").select("aid","DId","BM","BY","TO","cid").groupBy(aid","DId","BM","BY")select("aid","DId","BM","BY","TO","cid").show
```

Cant find out where I am doing wrong
Error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'cid' is ambiguous, could be: cid#4058, cid#13063L.;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Tempity("cid")` instead of `cid` as it's ambiguous

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ //for min()

val RS = Tempity.join(DF_LES, 
          Tempity("cid") <=> DF_PLES("cid") && 
          DF_PLES("clientid") <=> 2 && 
          Tempity("TO") <=> DF_PLES("PType") && 
          DF_PLES("pto") <=> "cccc", 
        "inner"
      )
    .groupBy("a​id","DId","BM","BY", Tempity("cid"))‌​
    .agg(min(DF_PLES("PS")))

RS.show()
```

Another way is you can use **same SQL on `SparkSession`**

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate;

//create tables from DataFrames
Tempity.createOrReplaceTempView("Tempity")
DF_PLES.createOrReplaceTempView("ples")

import spark.sql

//Now run the same SQL 

sql("""
    SELECT t.ad, t.DId, t.BY, t.BM, t.cid, MIN(p.PS) AS PS
      FROM Tempity t
    INNER JOIN ples p
      ON t.cid = p.cid AND p.PType = t.TeO AND p.pto = 'cccc' AND p.cid = 2
    GROUP BY t.ad, t.DId, t.BY, t.BM, t.cid
    """)
```

Comment: `<console>:49: error: value select is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset`

Comment: Error is is thrown for `val RS = Tempity.join(DF_LES, 
          Tempity("cid") <=> DF_PLES("cid") && 
          DF_PLES("clientid") <=> 2 && 
          Tempity("TO") <=> DF_PLES("PType") && 
          DF_PLES("pto") <=> "cccc", 
        "inner"
      )
    .groupBy("a​id","DId","BM","BY", Tempity("cid"))‌​
    .agg(min(DF_PLES("PS")))
` I want to perform operations on DF instead of using sql("")

Comment: It worked for me after drop("cid") from on of the table

Comment: great!! if possible add the data frame code in answer by editing it.